# Optimization in SQL with Nested Dynamic Variables

Tags: sql, loops, dynamic-variables

I have been asked to perform some excel like optimization in SQL. I need to loop through some variables(which will take discrete values, jumping by 0.05) and find for each variable the value that minimizes a distance that is a function of that variable. I'm not very used to work with dynamic variables so any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

```
        --Loop trough each variable to be optimized
         declare @j as integer

        set @j = 1 
        while @j <= 50 
        begin 

        declare @i as integer
    set  @i=0
    --Here is where I don't know how to do it, I need the variable to be declared in each loop
    --If the next deviation is deviating from the prior, means that the prior iteration reached the best fit. Equations in this case are linear
    do while @deviation'+'@i <deviation'+'(@i-1)
    declare @deviation'+'@i as float

    --Update the table each time with the recalculated target variable

    Select a.*, a.product_price * b.product_fee as changing_value into calculator
    from product_tables a left join fee_table b
    on a.Product_code = b.Product_code
    Recalculate function distance to be minimized
    set @deviation'+'@i = sum(SQRT(Current_value - changing_value)^2)) from calculator
update fee_table
    set product_fee = product_fee +@i*0.05 where id_fee = @j
    set @i = i+1
    end
--- If the condition is met, means that the (@i-1) value is the best fit
update fee_table
    set product_fee = product_fee +(@i-1)*0.05 where id_fee = @j

    set @j= j+1
    end
```

I apologize in advance for the inconsistencies you may find in the code. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: What database are you using? There are some techniques that would be better than looping (which is generally not the best way to go in SQL) but some of them are vendor specific.

Comment: I am using SQL, I have hundred of thousand of products, so I believe doing it in excel won't be the best idea in terms of perfomance.

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server or Postgresql or (etc)? I agree though, Excel would not be the best choice.